# What's wrong about kuberent client demo error

Tags: go, kubernetes

download kubernetes sdk source  code

```
 git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go.git kubernet-client
```

and then
`cd kubernet-client/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/`
and
type `go run main.go` , has error

```
➜  in-cluster-client-configuration git:(master) go run main.go
# net
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.18.2/libexec/src/net/dial.go:351:11: d.DialContext undefined (type *Dialer has no field or method DialContext)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.18.2/libexec/src/net/dial.go:372:18: invalid character U+2013 '–' in identifier
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.18.2/libexec/src/net/lookup_unix.go:70:14: d.DialContext undefined (type Dialer has no field or method DialContext)
➜  in-cluster-client-configuration git:(master) pwd
go_sourcecode/kubernet-client/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration
```

the go version

```
➜  in-cluster-client-configuration git:(master) go version
go version go1.18.2 darwin/amd64
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The step-by-step process has been written in the markdown file (https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration), why you didn't follow that ?

As this is an in-cluster example, this has to be run from inside of a kubernetes cluster. `go run main.go` will not work. To run this,

1. make a binary : `go build -o ./app .`
2. build an image : `docker build -t YOUR_DOCKER_ID/controller:in-cluster .`
3. push it on docker hub: `docker push IMAGE`
   OR load this image into cluster. For kind cluster : `kind load docker-image IMAGE`
4. give permission to list pods : `kubectl create clusterrolebinding default-view --clusterrole=view --serviceaccount=default:default`
5. Then run `kubectl run --rm -i demo --image=IMAGE`